# Cannot configure Spring Data JPA: Specified class is an interface

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've started to use Spring Data JPA. Unfortunately I can't configure it. I have `Entity` class, `Repository` interface, but when I try to test it, something is wrong.

Source code(I have setter/getter methods, but I skipped it for better code):

```
@Entity 
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public Employee() {
} 
}
```

Repository class:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.szymon.repository")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.szymon.repository")
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    localEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("postgres");
    return localEntityManagerFactoryBean;
}
}
```

When I try to test it:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = EmployeeRepository.class)
public class EmployeeRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

@Test
public void test() {
    Employee employee = new Employee("Szymon", "Nowak");
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
}
```

i'm getting error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.szymon.repository.EmployeeRepository]: Specified class is an interface
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.szymon.repository.EmployeeRepository]: Specified class is an interface
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
... 44 more
```

I was testing it before with simple `EntityManager` create, and hibernate created tables in database, so I think database layer is ok.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your test is annotated with `@ContextConfiguration(classes = EmployeeRepository.class)`

However, the `classes` property of this annotation should reference configurations (class annotated with `@Configuration` like your `AppConfig`). So you are launching your test without a configuration for spring-data and your repository.

If you want to test your repository, you should create a @Configuration with the `@EnableJpaRepositories` and an in-memory database.