# SpringBoot Test JPA repository error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

I have a springboot application and a JPARepository interface defined.

I have a BeansConfigTest config class where I am autowiring the JPARepository and there is a test class.

While running test cases I am getting exception :

```
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.MyMetaInfoRepository]: Specified class is an interface
    10:59:08,770  INFO main LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:destroy:548 - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    10:59:08,791  INFO main AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer:logAutoConfigurationReport:
```

My application-properties class is :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:UserAttributeConfig;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password =
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

and BeanConfifTest class has annotations

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.configtest","com.example.db.repository"},
       excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
              value = CommandLineRunner.class))
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class BeansConfigTest {
..}
```

What could be the issue of this error?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827372/cannot-configure-spring-data-jpa-specified-class-is-an-interface

Comment: still getting the same error even on adding @EnableJpaRepositories

Comment: Why aren't you using @SpringBootApplication annotation? it replaces Configuration, EnableAutoConfiguration and ComponentScan