# Spring Boot WebFluxTest test, failed to instantiate repository, specified class is an interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing

I am writing the integration tests with `@WebFluxTest` for my `@RestController`.
Here are my classes:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/usager")
public class UsagerController {

    @Autowired
    private UsagerService usagerService;

    @GetMapping
    public Usager getUsager() {
        return usagerService.create();
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class UsagerService implements CrudService<Usager, Integer> {

    @Autowired
    private UsagerRepository usagerRepository;

    @Override
    public JpaRepository<Usager, Integer> getRepository() {
        return usagerRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Usager create() {
        return new Usager();
    }

}
```

```
@Repository
public interface UsagerRepository extends JpaRepository<Usager, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Usager> {

}
```

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest(UsagerController.class)
@Import({ UsagerService.class, UsagerRepository.class })
@Tag(TestCase.INTEGRATION)
public class UsagerControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient wtc;

    @Test
    public void getUsager_returnUsager() {
        ResponseSpec rs = wtc.get().uri("/usager").exchange();

        rs.expectStatus().isOk();
        rs.expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        rs.expectBody(Usager.class).isEqualTo(new Usager());
    }

}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.dsi.bibliosys.biblioback.repository.UsagerRepository]: Specified class is an interface
```

I don't understand why Spring can't inject the repository.
Does somebody have an idea ?

---

I tried another approach using `@SpringBootTest`. Here is my new test class :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Tag(TestCase.INTEGRATION)
public class UsagerController02IT {

    @Autowired
    private UsagerController usagerController;

    @Test
    public void getUsager_returnUsager() {
        WebTestClient wtc = WebTestClient.bindToController(usagerController).build();

        ResponseSpec rs = wtc.get().uri("/usager").exchange();

        rs.expectStatus().isOk();
        rs.expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        rs.expectBody(Usager.class).isEqualTo(new Usager());
    }

}
```

I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.dsi.bibliosys.biblioback.controller.UsagerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usagerService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dsi.bibliosys.biblioback.service.entity.UsagerService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I don't understand why `UserService` is not available in the application context.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827372/cannot-configure-spring-data-jpa-specified-class-is-an-interface/35827491). I'd suggest investigating your test configuration and adding it if appropriate.

A [quote](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/reactive/WebFluxTest.html) from Spring on `@WebFluxTest`

**Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to WebFlux tests (i.e. @Controller, @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent, Converter/GenericConverter, and WebFluxConfigurer beans but not @Component, @Service or @Repository beans).**